# Initializing an array with an existing array and variables

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a string array from an existing string and a string array as follows

```
string[] oldArray = { "Hello", "World" };
string oldString = "test string";
string[] newArray = { oldArray, oldString };
```

This is, unfortunately, not going to work as written, so I have been trying to come up with a non-iterating method of filling the `newArray` with the elements of the old.  The only solution I have found is to join with an arbitrary character(s) and then split using the same.

```
string[] arr = {"AString", "BString", "CString" }; // Passed to function
...
string arrAsString = String.Join("$", arr) + "$" + DateTime.Today.ToString("M/dd");
return arrAsString.Split('$');
```

But this is much slower in my tests than a `for` loop.  Are there any better solutions?

Edit: In response to an answer below: The reason why I was not using List is because I am manipulating cells in Excel, and ranges in the API I am using are returned as arrays

Comment: This is a major reason why the collections classes exist. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx

Comment: Side note: consider adding information on why you actually trying  to do that - could be even better way than using `List<string>`/ `IEnumerable<string>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using  [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```
string[] newArray = oldArray.Concat(new [] { oldString }).ToArray();
```

Or, use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead if you don't want a *fixed size* collection.

Comment: Concat seems to be exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

> The only solution I have found is to join with an arbitrary character(s) and then split using the same.

Please don't do it this way! For one, if any of your strings have a `$` in them, you'll get unexpected results.

You should probably be using a [`List<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). It's much like a `string[]`, but it has a variable size.

```
var myList = new List<string> { "Hello", "World" };
myList.Add("test string");
```

Comment: In my usage, there will never be a `$` in the string, but I realized this was poor form.  The reason why I was not using `List<string>` is because I am manipulating cells in Excel, and ranges in the API I am using are returned as arrays.

Comment: You can do `ToList()` and `ToArray()` to convert between the two. Or create an array that's the new size, and use `Array.Copy` to move items (if that sounds like the way you'd want to go, I could edit it into my answer), or `Concat` like Selman22 answered.